# static_cast fails only after deleting elements of a pointer array

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a series of classes that inherit from a parent action class. I also have an array of action pointers:

```
Action **currentActions;
```

and later:

```
currentActions = new Action*[numActions];
```

I am looping through these action pointers, casting them to the child classes, and then using them. I am doing this with a static cast as below:

```
Action*A = currentActions[currentActionIteration];
ConstVelAction* velAction = static_cast<ConstVelAction*>(A);
```

This works perfectly fine as is. ***However***, when I delete the elements in the action array and then try to static cast the elements in the same way, I find that the static cast is not successful. No errors are thrown, and the code still compiles, but I find that some of the values in the casted object are not what they should be. (They have a value of 0 as opposed to 50)

How I am deleting the elements in the array:

```
//Delete the old actions if any are there
    for (int i = 0; i < numCurrentActions; i++) {
        delete currentActions[i];
    }
```

If instead of deleting elements, I simply overwrite the old elements in the array and don't delete them as above, the cast works successfully. Thus, I know that it is the one delete line that is causing the issues. However, since my array could be changing size, I want to delete them.

**What is going on here? Is there an alternative way to accomplish what I am after? Should I be using something other than delete?**

For further information: This is running on Arduino with vMicro.

---

---

---

I think I've provided everything needed, but if not, for reference, here are larger sections of my code:

Declaration of currentActions in header:

```
Action **currentActions;
```

This is the function where I delete the old action list:

```
void ActionScheduler::addInstructionSet(char *actionString[]) {

    digitalWrite(7, LOW);

    //Delete the old actions if any are there
    for (int i = 0; i < numCurrentActions; i++) {
        delete currentActions[i];
    }

    int numActions = 0;
    //Count the number of actions in the string so as to not dynamically allocate

    int i = 0;
    char c = (*actionString)[0];
    while (c != '\0') {
        i++;
        c = (*actionString)[i];
        if (c == ACTION_SEPERATOR[0]) {
            numActions++;
        }
    }

    currentActions = new Action*[numActions];

    int currentAction = 0;
    char* action = strtok(*actionString, SEPERATORS);
    
    action = strtok(NULL, SEPERATORS);//Do it again to get past the type of write 


    while (action != NULL) {
        //The action has been identified, now need to create the according action

        switch (action[0]) {
        case 'd'://delay
        {
            int delay = atoi(++action);//++ is to skip the , 
            currentActions[currentAction] = new DelayAction(delay);
            break;
        }
        case CONST_VEL_MVMT://constant velocity
        {

            // format is speed, xposition, yposition

            
            int speed = atoi(++action);//++ is to skip the , 
            action = strtok(NULL, SEPERATORS);
            int xPosition = atoi(action);//++ is to skip the identifier
            action = strtok(NULL, SEPERATORS);
            int yPosition = atoi(action);//++ is to skip the identifier

            currentActions[currentAction] = new ConstVelAction(xPosition, yPosition, speed, xStepper, yStepper);

            break;
        }

        case LINEAR_ACCEL_MVMT://constant velocity
        {
            // format is acceleration, initial velocity, xdisplacment, ydisplacement

            float acceleration = atof(++action);//++ is to skip the , 
            action = strtok(NULL, SEPERATORS);
            float initialVelocity = atof(action);
            action = strtok(NULL, SEPERATORS);
            float xDisplacement = atof(action);
            action = strtok(NULL, SEPERATORS);
            float yDisplacement = atof(action);

            currentActions[currentAction] = new LinAccelAction(acceleration, initialVelocity, xDisplacement, yDisplacement, xStepper, yStepper);

            break;
        }
        default:
            Serial.println(F("Unrecognized Action Type:"));
        }

        currentAction++;
        action = strtok(NULL, SEPERATORS);
    }
    numCurrentActions = numActions;
    currentActionIteration = 0;
    iteratingThroughActions = true;

}
```

This is the function where I perform the static cast:

```
void ActionScheduler::update() {

    if (!iteratingThroughActions) {
        (*xStepper).update();
        (*yStepper).update();
    }
    else {

        if (waitingForStepper) {
            if ((*xStepper).getCurrentState() == (*xStepper).STOPPED && (*yStepper).getCurrentState() == (*yStepper).STOPPED) {
                Serial.println("STEPPER STOPPED");
                currentActionIteration++;
                waitingForStepper = false;
            }
            else {
                (*xStepper).update();
                (*yStepper).update();
            }
        }
        else if (waitingForDelay) {
            if ((millis() - delayStartTime) >= currentTimeDelay) {
                Serial.println("END OF DELAY");
                //waited long enough
                waitingForDelay = false;
                currentActionIteration++;
            }
        }
        else {//Not waiting for anything

            //No more actions are left
            if (currentActionIteration >= numCurrentActions) {
                iteratingThroughActions = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < numCurrentActions; i++) {
                    delete currentActions[i];
                }
                return;
            }

            //have to go through action list

            switch (currentActions[currentActionIteration]->type) {
            case CONSTVELTYPE: {
                Serial.println("START OF VELOCITY");
                Action*A = currentActions[currentActionIteration];
                ConstVelAction* velAction = static_cast<ConstVelAction*>(A);
                Serial.print("Vel Action Speed");
                Serial.println((*velAction).getSpeed());
                velAction->implement();
                velAction->startAction();
                waitingForStepper = true;
                break;
            }
            case LINACCELTYPE: {
                Serial.println("START OF Linear Acceleration");
                Action*A = currentActions[currentActionIteration];
                LinAccelAction* velAction = static_cast<LinAccelAction*>(A);
                velAction->implement();
                velAction->startAction();
                waitingForStepper = true;
                break;
            }
            case DELAYTYPE: {
                Serial.println("START OF DELAY");
                Serial.print(currentActionIteration);
                delayStartTime = millis();
                currentTimeDelay = currentActions[currentActionIteration]->timeToComplete;
                waitingForDelay = true;
                break;
            }
            default: {
                Serial.print(F("Unrecognized action in list"));
                Serial.print(currentActions[currentActionIteration]->type);
                Serial.print(F(" Location "));
                Serial.print(currentActionIteration);
                Serial.print(F(" Num Actions "));
                Serial.println(numCurrentActions);
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `dynamic_cast` for "safe" casting from parent to child (you still need to test for null pointers). `static_cast`  is only safe for casting from child to parent (and usually not needed).  See _"... Such a downcast makes no runtime checks to ensure that the object's runtime type is actually D..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

Comment: You can't use dynamic_cast in arduino easily because rtti is disabled to save on memory. There are ways to reenable it, but I don't want to. 

I am confident that the static cast is converting to the right type, because I am using ID's in the parent Action class that indicate the type. This is what the following switch statement refers to:
switch (currentActions[currentActionIteration]->type)

Example reference on RTTI/semi-similar id approach:https://eliwinkelman.github.io/Arduino-DIY-Dynamic-Cast/

Comment: @RichardCritten> dynamic cast is not magic, and will not fix bugs in your code. There is nothing inherently safe about it. It is just a different tool, for a different purpose. And that purpose is unrelated to the problem at hand.

Comment: It is hard to follow with just bits of the full code. For instance we do not even see the declaration of relevant classes. If it is too big to post, you could trim it down into an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people have a better chance to understand what happens in it.

Comment: @spectras I never said it was safe.  I said you need to test the result of the cast.  It will also confirm or disprove type of pointed to object.  There is just too much code so we need to start a process of elimination.

Answer (score 0):

In your ActionScheduler::addInstructionSet function
The currentActions variable is being allocated each time through the function:

```cpp
currentActions = new Action*[numActions];
```

but after you deleted all the actions:

```cpp
//Delete the old actions if any are there
    for (int i = 0; i < numCurrentActions; i++) {
        delete currentActions[i];
    }
```

you also need to use operator delete[] on currentActions, since you allocated currentActions with operator new[]:

```cpp
   delete[] currentActions;
```

As far as the rest of the code, it is difficult to say without knowing more details about the Action class and its derived classes.